# 500 error when using wp_upload_dir()

Tags: php

I'm using wp_upload_dir() within my plugin directory so that I can create a folder if it doesn't exist before uploading images to the directory. And for some reason it gives a 500 error during my ajax call.

my code looks like this

```
<?php


$upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
$user_dir_name = $upload_dir['basedir'].'/mg_gallery';

if( ! file_exists( $user_dir_name ) ) {

  if ( wp_mkdir_p( $user_dir_name ) ) {

    $is_successful = true;
  } else {

    $error_msg = "Sorry Couldn't create directory. ";
    $is_successful = false;
  }

}
```

Comment: Have you enabled `WP_DEBUG`? Are you sure that `$upload_dir` contains the `base_dir` key?

Comment: I do have WP_DEBUG enabled. And I don't think the```$upload_dir``` contains the```base_dir``` key cause when I echo it out I get nothing returned in during my request. How would I go about ensuring that it has it?

Comment: I have a feeling that it's not somehow included or capable of using the funciton but i'm not sure why that is the case or what file to include if that's the case

Comment: Do you know to read the response from the web server based on your the Ajax call? What is the exact ajax url?

Comment: the post response when I echo out ```$upload_dir['basedir']``` is nothing.

Comment: Where is this code located? Are you calling it within a hook/filter?

Comment: So it seems as though the function ```wp_upload_dir()``` is not declared because I made a blank one inside the same file and the response went through without any errors. Is there a file I can include in order to use it within the file and why is this necessary.

Comment: i'm calling it from a subdirectory within a plugin i'm trying to build

Comment: it's within the file i'm making an ajax call with. not in a filter or hook

Comment: You should do the AJAX call the WordPress way so you can have access to the WP functions https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Comment: Also you get 500 on fatal errors, so try to avoid fatal errors :)

Comment: so i'm tried the wp_ajax and i'm getting a 0 as it's response.
it says it may be the naming scheme but i've got funciton names ```mg_ajax_javascript()``` and ```mg_ajax_callback()```; and add actions like:

```add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', array( &$this, 'mg_ajax_javascript' ) );
  add_action( 'wp_ajax_mg_ajax', array( &$this, 'mg_ajax_callback' ) );```

Comment: now I have to figure out how to import my ajax file into the calback function cause I don't want all that in the same file as my plugin class.

Comment: do you want to put your response as an answer

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This was occurring because I wasn't using wp's built in ajax.